# document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined in GM script, works in JS

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am trying to use this line of JavaScript as a GreaseMonkey script:

```
javascript: document.getElementsByClassName("widget-contents")[0].style.height='640px';void(0);
```

I tried to convert it into a GreaseMonkey script as such:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        First GM Script
// @namespace   http://www.example.net/
// @description first gm script
// @include     https//www.example.net/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
document.getElementsByClassName('widget-contents') [0].style.height = '640px';
```

and I am getting this error:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined
```

Could someone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your script is probably running before element you've looking for is rendered. Check GM start time options or otherwise delay execution.

Comment: @Oleg I tried adding `// @run-at document-end` and `document-idle` but that didn't work.

Comment: @kolarek can you try `document.querySelector('widget-contents').style.height = ...`, if you will get same-ish error, than indeed you are requesting the element that does not exist yet

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
document.onload = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('widget-contents') [0].style.height = '640px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Oleg I tried to delay the execution of my code, finally this is the whole code:

```
function enlarger () {
    document.getElementsByClassName('widget-contents') [0].style.height = '640px';
}
setTimeout (enlarger, 2000);
```

thus delaying the execution of `enlarger` by 2 seconds.